# Как из контейнера docker получить ip и порт, на котором хостится этот контейнер на хостинге?

Tags: python-3.x, веб-программирование, docker, devops

Суть такая: пишу сайт-сократитель ссылок в качестве учебного проекта (впервые в жизни делаю сайт и уж тем более контейнеризирую что-то). Сайт принимает на вход данные и генерирует для них короткую ссылку, которая состоит из, собственно, генерируемой части и адреса сервера сайта. Я собрал образ для сайта, загрузил его на докер хаб и развернул сайт на хостинге. Всё заработало, но вылезла одна большая проблема: сайт берёт ip из окружения в контейнере, и поэтому он как бы виден, на него можно зайти и даже получить ссылку, но ссылка сгенерируется с помощью внутреннего ip контейнера, и поэтому она будет нерабочей. Как мне программно получить внешний ip и порт (их генерация зависит от хостинга), на которых хостится сайт? И если это неэффективный вариант, то какие есть альтернативы (я думал купить домен и сделать всё через него, но не уверен, что это сработает)?

Comment: а зачем вам настоящий ip клиента? сайт для сокращения ссылок принимает короткий адрес и перенаправляет клиента на оригинальный, напримерт. my.app/XXXYYY -> google.com

Comment: @ExplodingKitten речь не про ip клиента, а про ip сервера

Comment: Но и знать ip сервера тоже нафиг не нужно, нужно делать такую генерацию, которая НЕ будет зависеть от хостинга

Comment: Вместо ip указывайте доменное имя сервера. Причем для учебных целей можно даже не покупать ничего, а просто в hosts прописывать.